# PHP - read zip file contents without saving on server

Tags: php, zip

I have a remote ZIP file, and I need to read the content of a file located in the zip file, without having to copy the zip file to our server. There should be some solution to solve this, but I can't find it.

Example:
URL - http://example.com/feed.zip and
File in the ZIP Archive is feed.xml

I need to read the content of `feed.xml` and save it in one variable. Thats it.

I have try with `$z = new ZipArchive();` and open, but open can only read files from the server and not remote files.

Comment: Why don't you copy it on the server, read it and then delete it ? It's the same amount of traffic...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem and the best I could get was saving zip content to temp file and using [`ZipArchive`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.ziparchive.php) to get content of zipped file:

```
public static function unzip($zipData) {
    // save content into temp file
    $tempFile = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'feed');
    file_put_contents($tempFile, $zipData);

    // unzip content of first file from archive
    $zip = new ZipArchive();
    $zip->open($tempFile);
    $data = $zip->getFromIndex(0);

    // cleanup temp file
    $zip->close();
    unlink($tempFile);

    return $data;
}
```

This is basically implementation of @mauris suggestion.

Answer (score 5):

A super lazy solution would be:

```
$feed = `wget http://example.com/feed.zip -qO-  | unzip - -p feed.xml`;
```

Note that the url should be escaped (escapeshellarg) if it's not a fixed string.

But you could also investigate other ZIP classes than the built-in ZipArchive. PEAR or PclZip might allow to read from streams without workarounds. (But php://memory or a string stream wrapper might be feasible as well, if you're really bent on eschewing temporary files.)

Comment: Mario, what about `php://temp`? The only problem I came up with in using this is that once the file pointer is closed, the file is gone. My idea would be: write to temp, rewind file, pass file pointer to ZipArchive (somehow?)

Answer (score 2):

That requires the concept of **temporary files**. Technically speaking: yes, you are going to make a temporary copy of the remote zip file that is locally available because your `ZipArchive` does not work on remote zip files at all.

Following these steps to implement temporary copy should help you:

1. Make a copy of the remote zip file to a temporary folder.
2. Use `ZipArchive` to parse the local copy of the zip file.
3. Read information in your feed.xml file.
4. Close and everything and delete the local copy of the zip file.

Comment: Yes, I know that this works in this way, but it is not the best way. That means I need to have on every server where my files are running the same dir structure etc. It's not the best way I think. Is there other option?

Comment: @Niko - You don't need the same directory structure as the zip file on your server: you process the files directly from the zip file, not unzip and walk the files